# Why did a `400 exception` error occurred when I tried to insert multiple time series at one time in Apache IoTDB Version 1.2?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, when I tried to insert 2000 time series data at one time using Version 1.2 of Apache IoTDB, a `org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 400` error was reported. Can this be adjusted? Which settings should I make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `session` version in Apache IoTDB. See if you are using, for example, 0.13 or older version of `session`, and you can upgrade it to version 1.2.